# Programa.exe ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: c++, windows

estoy con este código, un poco feo. Quiero saber porque me sale

> Programa.exe ha dejado de funcionar

Llevo bastante buscando el error, gracias de antemano.

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <windows.h>
            using namespace std;

            struct Medico{
                string nombre;
                string especialidad;
                string servicios[2];
            };
            struct Paciente{
                string nombre;
                int edad;
                int seguro;
                int recaudado;
            };


            int acseguro(int,Paciente[],int);
            void recaudos(int,int,int);
            //void  moc(string[],int,string[], int);
            int main()
            {
                SetConsoleTitle("El Paciente Feliz");
                int ocurrencias[7][4];
                int tota=0,totb=0,totc=0,totd=0,totaa=0,totbb=0,totcc=0,totdd=0,totaaa=0,totbbb=0,totccc=0,totddd=0,totaaaa=0,totbbbb=0,totcccc=0,totdddd=0,totaaaaa=0,totbbbbb=0,totccccc=0,totddddd=0,totaaaaaa=0,totbbbbbb=0,totcccccc=0,totdddddd=0,totaaaaaaa=0,totbbbbbbb=0,totccccccc=0,totddddddd=0;
                int dinero=0,ingresado=0,cantidadserv,cantidadespe,monto=0,posesp=0,posser=0,costo=0,paga,recaucentro=0,contpacientes=0,totpacientes=0;;
                string espe[5],serv[5];
                Paciente pacien[10];
                float seguro[4]={1,0.1,0.5,0.10};
                int ocurrenciass[7][4],e=7,s=4,precios[e][s]={{45000,500000,15000,25000},{25000,250000,15000,15000},{45000,300000,40000,0},{25000,300000,20000,0},{30000,500000,25000,0},{10000,150000,10000,10000},{15000,300000,15000,0}};
                string especialidades[7]={"cardiologia","traumatologia","oncologia","otorrinolaringologia","neurologia","optometria","ginecologia"};
                string servicios[4]={"consulta","cirugia","examen","terapia"};

                { //matriz de precios
                cout<<"\n"<<"\n";
                cout<<"\t" <<"\t" <<"\t"<<"\t"<<"Bienvenido al Centro Medico El Paciente Feliz."<<"\n";
                cout<<"                 __________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<"\n"<<"\n";
                cout<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"Consulta"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"Cirug"<<char(161)<<"a"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"Examen"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"Terapia"<<"\n";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Cardiolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$45.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$500.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$15.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$25.000";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Traumatolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$25.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$250.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$15.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$15.000";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Oncolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$45.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$300.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$40.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$0";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Otorrinolaringolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"$25.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$300.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$20.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$0";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Nerolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$30.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$500.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$25.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$0";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Optometr"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$10.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$150.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$10.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$10.000";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Ginecolog"<<char(161)<<"a:"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$15.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$300.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$15.000"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"\t"<<"$0"<<endl;
                cout<<"                 __________________________________________________________________________________________________";
                cout<<"\n \n";
                cout<<"SEGUROS";
                cout<<"\n";
                cout<<"\n"<<"Tipo 1: 0%"<<"\t"<<"Tipo 2: 10%"<<"\t"<<"Tipo 3: 50%"<<"\t"<<"Tipo 4: 100%"<<"\n \n";
                cout<<endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");

                cout<<"          _____________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |                                                                                                     |"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |En el centro medico el 'El Paciente Feliz' trabajamos por ti, por favor llena los siguientes datos :)|"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |_____________________________________________________________________________________________________|"<<endl;

                cout<<"\n";
                }

                for(int w=0;w<10;w++){
                    cout<<"Bienvenido, ingresa tu nombre: ";
                    cin>>pacien[w].nombre;
                    cout<<"Ingresa tu edad, "<<pacien[w].nombre<<": "; //acá leo el valor y saco precio

                    cin>>pacien[w].edad;
                    cout<<"Ingresa tu tipo de seguro: ";
                    cin>>pacien[w].seguro;
                    cout<<"\n"<<char(168)<<"En cu"<<char(160)<<"ntas especialidades necesitas ser atentido?: ";
                    cin>>cantidadespe;

                        for(int i=0;i<cantidadespe;i++){
                            cout<<char(168)<<"En qu"<<char(130)<<" especialidad deseas ser atentido?: ";
                            cin>>espe[i];
                            for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
                                    if(especialidades[j]==espe[i]){
                                        posesp=j;
                                    }
                            }


                            cout<<char(168)<<"Cu"<<char(160)<<"ntos servicios necesitas de "<<espe[i]<<"?: ";
                            cin>>cantidadserv;

                                for(int k=0;k<cantidadserv;k++){
                                    cout<<char(168)<<"Qu"<<char(130)<<" servicio deseas para "<<espe[i]<<"?: ";
                                    cin>>serv[k];
                                        for(int p=0;p<4;p++){
                                                if(servicios[p]==serv[k]){
                                                    posser=p;
                                                }
                                    }
                                    costo=costo+precios[posesp][posser];
                                    paga=acseguro(costo,pacien,w);


                        {//no abrir, no mover

                    if((espe[i]=="cardiologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        tota++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="cardiologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="cardiologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="cardiologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="traumatologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="trumatologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="traumatologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totcc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="traumatologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totdd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="oncologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="oncologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="oncologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totccc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="oncologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totddd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="otorrinolaringologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaaaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="otorrinolaringologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbbbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="otorrinolaringologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totcccc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="otorrinolaringologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totdddd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="neurologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaaaaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="neurologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbbbbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="neurologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totccccc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="neurologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totddddd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="optometria")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaaaaaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="optometria")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbbbbbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="optometria")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totcccccc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="optometria")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totdddddd++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="ginecologia")&&(serv[k]=="consulta")){
                        totaaaaaaa++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="ginecologia")&&(serv[k]=="cirugia")){
                        totbbbbbbb++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="ginecologia")&&(serv[k]=="examen")){
                        totccccccc++;
                        }
                    if((espe[i]=="ginecologia")&&(serv[k]=="terapia")){
                        totddddddd++;
                        }
                    }
                        {//no abrir, no mover




                    while(1==1){
                            ocurrencias[0][0]=tota;
                            ocurrencias[0][1]=totb;
                            ocurrencias[0][2]=totc;
                            ocurrencias[0][3]=totd;
                            ocurrencias[1][0]=totaa;
                            ocurrencias[1][1]=totbb;
                            ocurrencias[1][2]=totcc;
                            ocurrencias[1][3]=totdd;
                            ocurrencias[2][0]=totaa;
                            ocurrencias[2][1]=totbb;
                            ocurrencias[2][2]=totcc;
                            ocurrencias[2][3]=totdd;
                            ocurrencias[3][0]=totaaa;
                            ocurrencias[3][1]=totbbb;
                            ocurrencias[3][2]=totccc;
                            ocurrencias[3][3]=totddd;
                            ocurrencias[4][0]=totaaaa;
                            ocurrencias[4][1]=totbbbb;
                            ocurrencias[4][2]=totcccc;
                            ocurrencias[4][3]=totdddd;
                            ocurrencias[5][0]=totaaaaa;
                            ocurrencias[5][1]=totbbbbb;
                            ocurrencias[5][2]=totccccc;
                            ocurrencias[5][3]=totddddd;
                            ocurrencias[6][0]=totaaaaaa;
                            ocurrencias[6][1]=totbbbbbb;
                            ocurrencias[6][2]=totcccccc;
                            ocurrencias[6][3]=totdddddd;
                            ocurrencias[7][0]=totaaaaaaa;
                            ocurrencias[7][1]=totbbbbbbb;
                            ocurrencias[7][2]=totccccccc;
                            ocurrencias[7][3]=totddddddd;

                            break;
                    }
            }


                                }
                        }
                        recaucentro=recaucentro+paga;
                        recaudos(paga,recaucentro,costo);
                        costo=0;
                        contpacientes++;


                        system("PAUSE");

               {
                system("CLS");
                cout<<"          _____________________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |                                                                                                     |"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |En el centro medico el 'El Paciente Feliz' trabajamos por ti, por favor llena los siguientes datos :)|"<<endl;
                cout<<"         |_____________________________________________________________________________________________________|"<<endl;

                cout<<"\n";
               }
            }
                for(int m=0;m<7;m++){
                        for(int n=0;n<4;n++){
                            cout<<ocurrencias[m][n]<<"\t";
                        }
                        cout<<"\n";
                    }

            }


            int acseguro(int costo,Paciente pacien[10],int w){

                int deuda=0;
                switch(pacien[w].seguro){
                case 1:   deuda=costo;
                            break;
                case 2:   deuda=costo-(costo*0.1)+1;
                            break;
                case 3:   deuda=costo-(costo*0.5);
                            break;
                case 4:   deuda=0;
                            break;
                default:    break;
                }
                return deuda;
            }

            void recaudos(int paga, int recaucentro, int costo){
                    cout<<"\n"<<"La deuda es de "<<costo<<", aplicando descuento de seguro queda en "<<paga<<endl;
                    cout<<"El recaudado por el Centro Medico es de "<<recaucentro<<endl;
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

> estoy con este codigo, un poco feo ...

Es más sencillo encontrar errores (o incluso evitar cometerlos) en códigos limpios y legibles que en entramados propios de una película de miedo.

Por otro lado no termino de entender los motivos que llevan a que el código que presentes sea capaz de mostrar el mensaje que indicas:

**error 1**

```
main.cpp:24: error: C2664: 'BOOL SetConsoleTitleW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [18]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Concretamente aquí:

```
SetConsoleTitle("El Paciente Feliz");
```

¿Por qué? La función es de Windows y, la misma, requiere un parámetro de tipo [`LPCWSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx) (un alias de `const wchar_t*`) y tu le estás pasando un `char*`... que no es lo mismo. Tienes que añadir el prefijo `L` a la cadena:

```
SetConsoleTitle(L"El Paciente Feliz");
//              ^
```

**error 2**

```
main.cpp:31: error: C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

Aquí:

```
precios[e][s]=
```

¿Por qué?

`e` y `s` son variables y `precios` una matriz con dimensiones `e` y `s`. Esto se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y es una característica no contemplada en el estándar de C++... así que tienes muchas papeletas para que tu código no funcione en segun qué compiladores.

Si los valores de `e` y `s` son fijos plantéate usar constantes:

```
const int e = 7;
const int s = 4;
int precios[e][s] = { /* ... */ };
```

y, claro, si ya tienes unas variables (o constantes) para controlar estas dimensiones... **úsalos**:

```
// mal
for(int m=0;m<7;m++){
  for(int n=0;n<4;n++){
    cout<<ocurrencias[m][n]<<"\t";
  }
  cout<<"\n";
}

// bien
for(int m=0;m<e;m++){
  for(int n=0;n<s;n++){
    cout<<ocurrencias[m][n]<<'\t';
  }
  cout<<'\n';
}
```

Adicionalmente te falta incluir la cabecera `#include <string>` para poder usar correctamente el tipo `std::string`.

Y no olvides repasar la ristra de *warnings*. Si el compilador te está dando tantos avisos es por algo.

Después de todo esto el programa compila, se ejecuta y no casca... He estado tentado de votar para cerrar esta pregunta por error tipográfico, pero creo que va a ser más instructivo que te deje estos pasos como respuesta para que veas y aprendas de tus errores.